# Using chown to change ownership on additional HDD

Tags: 20.04, chown, syntax

OS Linux 20.04. Having installed an additional HDD in position `/dev/sdc1` (Label Data 22) I am confronted with root as owner.

Is either of the following syntaxes correct in order to set me up as owner?

```
sudo chown Robert Data 22   
sudo chown Robert /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: The space in `Data 22` *might* cause a problem. At least in the `chown` as it will see `Data` as one file and then `22` as a second file.

Comment: Disk is installed permanent or removable (via usb) ? Please add this information in your post.

Comment: The chown is only for Linux formatted partitions. It does not work on Windows formatted partitions like NTFS or FAT32. For t;hose your mount gives you permissions you need to use NTFS. So what is partition? Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 2):

Generally one would change the permissions via the mount point rather than the device name. For example, if the device you listed above is mounted at `/project/data`, then you could do something like this:

```
sudo chown robert:robert /project/data
```

If you wanted *every* file and directory contained in that path to also be owned by the account name, then you could add a `-R` to the command:

```
sudo chown -R robert:robert /project/data
```